# How to check if current page is a group entity?

Tags: 7, group

Im using drupal 7 and group module

I am trying to run some code only if the current page is a group.

here is my code

```
<?php
$arg = arg(0);
$arg1 = arg(1);
global $user;
if($arg ='group' && is_numeric($arg1)) {
    $group = group_load($arg1);
    if($group->getMember($user->uid)) { 
       print ('user is member');  
    };
};
?>
```

If this is placed on a group page it will print user is member if the current user is a member. If the current user isn't a member it will not show anything. Which is what it is supposed to do.

If I navigate to a none group page I get an error 'Error: Call to a member function getMember()',  but the if statement should prevent this?

How do I check if the current page is a group entity?

Thanks

Edit

I wanted to return true if a group page and user is a member of the group.
Using menu_get_object by Jaypan I used the code below to show. Im checking if page is group if so loading the group then checking if the user is a member of the group.

```
if (!empty(menu_get_object('group')))
   { 
   $group = group_load(arg(1));
   if($group->getMember($user->uid)) { 
       return TRUE;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the object for the current page in Drupal 7 using [menu_get_object()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7.x).

```
if ($group == menu_get_object('group')) {
  // do something with $group
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying but this doesn't work and I don't know the syntax to make it work. I think it isn't working because $group has already been loaded as a group, what I want to do is check that the path is a group before loading $group. So I need to get type from menu_get_object and check if it is of type group, if menu_get_object([0]) = 'group', or menu_get_object($type) = 'group'. But I do't know how to structure menu_get_object.

Comment: I managed to do it by checking if menu_get_object('group') is set first.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this doesn't work. It only loads $group when `menu_get_object('group')` returns a group. If you are on a group page, the `if()` conditional is entered. If you are not on a group page, the `if()` conditional is not entered. And when on a group page, this will load the group for you, so you don't need to call `node_load()` after the fact, as `menu_get_object('group')` will have already returned the group on group pages.

Comment: I put <?php
if ($group == menu_get_object('group')) {
 print ('true');
}
?>, nothing happened, I checked log it said group not defined, this was on a group page.

Comment: In Drupal, printing often doesn't print to the screen. Try `drupal_set_message('Here');`.

Answer (score 0):

checking if page is group if so loading the group then checking if the user is a member of the group.

```
if (!empty(menu_get_object('group')))
   { 
   $group = group_load(arg(1));
   if($group->getMember($user->uid)) { 
       return TRUE;  
    }
}
```